# How do I assign 'all' term to a node?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary (lets name it as 'Brands') which is getting filled by adding terms while creating a nodes.

I have a view which shows me the list of those nodes. This view has an exposed filters including the one filters nodes by Brand. There are nodes which must relate to all 'Brands'.

It is not possible to assign manually all existing brands to node while creating it because the vocabulary is kinda dynamic. That means they should pass filter with any term checked. Not when 'All', but when any of existing. It seems to be obvious but I can't see any way I can do that.

Comment: In the 3rd paragraph, you're talking about **nodes** then you say `That means they should pass filter with any term checked` you lost me here, are you talking about the filter in your view?

Comment: I'm sorry for my English.=\  I mean that some nodes must be assigned to all terms in 'Brands' vocabulary. They should be visible when I check any Brand (or Brends) in exposed filter of the view.

Comment: The should be visible no matter what brand is selected, right?

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Comment: You could just assign a "universal" tag to those nodes, like "always-visible" or whatever name and filter your list accordingly.

Comment: I thought about that. Seems a bit tricky for me. Like a not a _native_ way. I have to fill the tag filed with something like 'ALL' for each `universal` node, right? I'll do this way if there is no other. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you're going to filter the terms for specific brands, there's no indicator for an exception, so imho the "universal" nodes need a term that shows they are special. That also can be the absence of terms (e.g. filter: is empty) but then they won't show up when they have another term (a brand name e.g.). that's excluded by the filter. Having a specific term seems to be the safest way.

Answer (score 2):

it was so stupidly simple... Just don't add any term and add a filter to the view

`having Brand one of .... OR having Brand empty(NULL)`

I should definitely stop looking for a complex solutions for a simple questions. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well done! OR was the way to go...